# creating an open world island: Am I doing this correctly?

Tags: 3d, terrain, opengl-es2, open-world, godot-3

replicating minecraft but with better graphics is a pain (even very simple things using minecraft like chunks lag incredibly), so I'm just creating an open world that can be destroyed using some already made scripts that allow for environmental destruction.

I need to know if this method is correct.

1)The island is a square divided in a 7x7 grid creating 49 chunks including those underwater:

- duplicate the map to create multiple levels of detail
- Slice the chunks and separate them into different meshes thus different objects with different materials
- Texture the chunks and create multiple versions of the image with different levels of detail and size

2)Create separate models for  rocks, mountains, cliffs that can be placed anywhere

3)Place the Island chunks:

-create a script that tells godot to load the chunk meshes, with different LODS for different distances or if too far away to not load those chunks at all

4)Place mountains, trees, clifs, rocks and so on.

[image]

Comment: There's no such thing as "correct" in games. There's only "supports the gameplay / visuals / performance I want" and "doesn't". The person who can evaluate that is you. So, is this method delivering the results you want for your game so far? If so, great, keep going. If not, edit your question to identify the specific shortfall you need help overcoming.

Comment: @DMGregory mostly if it's actually possible

Comment: I don't think your concern is genuinely that you're hitting a fundamental limitation of computing like the Halting Problem. You know games have shipped with code that loads and unloads chunks at different levels of detail, etc. So you know this is computable, and you know Godot's environment is Turing complete - so if it's computable, code could be written to do it. You're just feeling anxiety because you've never written that code yourself before. The best way to overcome that is to push through and do it, and ask for help with a specific step in the process if it's giving you trouble.

Comment: Just keep in mind that open world games typically use tiling textures for the majority of their terrain. Even games using virtual texturing with theoretically unique textures at every point will still usually build those textures on demand from tiling / procedural layers, rather than having terabytes of unique per-chunk texture images saved on disc. You might drop down to pre-baked per-chunk textures for distant LOD versions though.